# CSS select second class child with variable div ID

Tags: css

The html:

```
<div class="test_name">
<div id ="1evhgctrq1bu51qgn9v81r38fhl_container" class="testing" </div>
<div id ="1evhgctrs18701vda1462185r1l_container" class="testing" </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
div#test_name .testing:nth-child(2) {
background:red;
}
```

The CSS doesn't work and i can't select those "1evhgctrs18701vda1462185r1l_container" div id's as they change every time.

Comment: `div#test_name` --> `div.test_name`

Comment: Doesn't work also :/

Comment: it does: https://jsfiddle.net/3e19Lu7h/1/

Answer (score 1):

There are  numerous ways of targetting that second nested div - as per the following

- using nth-child(2)
- using last-child
- using last-of-type
- using sibling combinator of the child div elements or their class
- using nth-child(even)
- using the :not() selector

Also note that in your code - you are not closing off the child divs, nor have andf content in them - which is probably why they are not rendering.

```css
.test_name .testing:nth-child(2),
.test_name-2 .testing:last-child,
.test_name-3 div:last-of-type,
.test_name-4 .testing + .testing,
.test_name-5 .testing:nth-child(even),
.test_name-6 .testing:not(:first-child){
  background: red;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<p> using nth-child(2)</p>
<div class="test_name">
  <div id ="1evhgctrq1bu51qgn9v81r38fhl_container" class="testing">testing 1</div>
  <div id ="1evhgctrs18701vda1462185r1l_container" class="testing">testing 2</div>
</div>
<hr/>

<p> using last-child</p>
<div class="test_name-2">
  <div id ="1evhgctrq1bu51qgn9v81r38fhl_container" class="testing">testing 1</div>
  <div id ="1evhgctrs18701vda1462185r1l_container" class="testing">testing 2</div>
</div>
<hr/>

<p> using last-of-type</p>
<div class="test_name-3">
  <div id ="1evhgctrq1bu51qgn9v81r38fhl_container" class="testing">testing 1</div>
  <div id ="1evhgctrs18701vda1462185r1l_container" class="testing">testing 2</div>
</div>
<hr/>

<p> using sibling combinator</p>
<div class="test_name-4">
  <div id ="1evhgctrq1bu51qgn9v81r38fhl_container" class="testing">testing 1</div>
  <div id ="1evhgctrs18701vda1462185r1l_container" class="testing">testing 2</div>
</div>
<hr/>

<p> using nth-child(even)</p>
<div class="test_name-5">
  <div id ="1evhgctrq1bu51qgn9v81r38fhl_container" class="testing">testing 1</div>
  <div id ="1evhgctrs18701vda1462185r1l_container" class="testing">testing 2</div>
</div>
<hr/>

<p> using :not() selector</p>
<div class="test_name-6">
  <div id ="1evhgctrq1bu51qgn9v81r38fhl_container" class="testing">testing 1</div>
  <div id ="1evhgctrs18701vda1462185r1l_container" class="testing">testing 2</div>
</div>
<hr/>
```